# Embed Existing .exe File inside a Webpage

Tags: exe, html

Can anyone please tell me how to embed existing .exe file inside a webpage? And that exe file should run in the context of the browser i.e it should not open a new window. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can't run an EXE from the browser without confirmation from the user, and you better believe that browsers try to make it obvious to the user that they could be doing something dangerous.

Comment: ok what if the targeted audience are comfortable with the exe running inside their browsers. So you're saying there ain't any way to embed exe. right?

Comment: Setup a Citrix, or Remote Desktop services.  Use one of the many flash/java/activex RDP/ICA plugins to connect to your terminal servers.

Comment: @Zoredache i didn't understand a word. i'm a newbie man. come on! lol

Answer (score -1):

You can use Friday13Games eRun to embed it into a browser. Simply go to Friday13Games.com/dev.php and click "Upload a Game".